# how to install a certificate to android emulator with a given pfx certificate file

Tags: android, android-studio, vpn

My requirement is, I have this certificate file with me, I have to install it on the Emulator in AVD.

When I push the file to the Emulator from the Android Device Manager I can not find it in the download or any where in the Emulator.

I am not able to install it directly from Command line as well the way we install an apk file.

When I try downloading it from a File server from the Emulator it takes lot of time and patience.

I do not want to install a file explorer for this is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by downloading the certificate file from the Web and install it after opening the certificate. It will ask for the password which is shared with the certificate and it was cleanly installed on the emulator.